# How to use the functools.partial on a function which has an argument which is a callable?

Tags: python, partial, functools

I'm trying to use the function partial from module functools on a callable which has an argument which is a function.
I've come up with a minimalist sample code.

```
from functools import partial

def g(f, x):
  return f(x)

def cube(x):  
  return x*x*x


p1 = partial(g, x=3)
abc = p1(cube) # works


p2 = partial( g, f=cube) 
abc = p2(3)    # fails TypeError: g() got multiple values for keyword argument 'f'
```

Can the function work with that case?

Thanks

Comment: In this statement `abc = p2(3)` you are reassigning 3 to **f** which is already assigned in the previous statement `partial( g, f=cube)`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not link to the type of the argument, the (partial) function call follows the rules https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls
The positional arguments are placed in the first parameter slots, then if *expression is present, expression is unzipped and placed in the next slots, finally if **expression is present, expression is mapped to function parameters and throws an error if parameter is already bound to an argument.

So

```
p2 = partial( g, f=cube) 
p2(3)    # fails
```

is the same as calling

```
g(3, f=cube)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the partial method from the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#partial-objects)

In partial we cannot pass two functions, so this may be the issue. Try to pass one function object and the second arg is the functional argument.

You can use this,

```
p2 = partial(g, f=cube, x=1)
abc = p2(x=3)
print(abc)
```

Hope this will help you.